# How can I find out whether there is an issue with the RAM interface of my system?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I'm currently using a PC based on a Ryzen 7 (3700X) on a Gigabyte GA-A320M-H board. DIMM 0 (left slot) works as desired, but DIMM 1 always raises a `PMU memory training error on channel 0, DIMM 1` when the BIOS displays its splash screen, no matter which DIMM I insert there (I'm using the Corsair Vengeance LPX 2× 16 GB kit). RAM interface parameters are all set to defaults (2.133 GHz). Memtest86 and the O/S (Linux; OpenSuSE Leap 15.1) don't even detect the second DIMM.

Now I would like to find out where there is something wrong with the CPU's memory interface, or the mainboard. Is it maybe possible to extract some kinda error log from the BIOS, which gives me more information than the abovementioned "training error"? Thank you.

Comment: I would at the very least examine the slot itself with magnification and a decent light source for any obstructions and/or look for any contacts that may have moved. A very many years ago, I had a contact move and was able to use a very fine pin to nudge it back into alignment.

Comment: OK, thx. I'm gonna inspect the slots.

Comment: Have you tried updating your BIOS?

Comment: When did you start to experience this behavior? Did you replace your processor and/or memory? Ryzen 3000  series processors (*Matisse*) aren't officially supported on A320 boards. B350 and X370 boards may accept them if appropriate BIOS updates are available. (Note that some motherboard manufacturers have in fact shipped updates to A320 boards that enable support for *Matisse* processors.) For compatibility details, see [this AMD chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll54B.jpg).

Comment: @Yorik: I have inspected both slots, and they both look absolutely identical to me. There is no visible damage, either. My dealer updated the BIOS to ver. F50. I've always experienced this behavior. Replacing the modules has not helped me at all.

Comment: @bwDraco: The 3700X is listed as a "Xen 2" processor. Is this already Gen. 3?? The Gigabyte product page for the A320M-H does list it as supported since firmware rev. F40: https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Motherboard/GA-A320M-H-rev-11/support#support-cpu